# Check box on GWT MenuItem

Tags: gwt, checkbox, menuitem

I have a GWT MenuBar where I need to add a MenuItem with a check box that can be set or reset by clicking on it.
I have seen similar functionality on smartgwt. Is there a way to have it on standard GWT?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about such widget. My advice would be to override MenuItem and add that checkbox in it.